# How to stop page from refreshing after confirmation box?

Tags: javascript, extjs, gwt, dom-events, jsni

I have this code inside a a method that forms a menu in Ext:

```
  handler: function() {
     var r = $wnd.confirm("Are you sure?");
  }
```

When I use `$wnd.alert`, it just shows a popup. When replaced with confirm, it works but then causes the whole page to refresh after a selection. Ideally, I'd like to use `$wnd.Ext.MessageBox.confirm`, but when I use that, I get the error cb.defer is not a function. Figuring out how to get the Javascript confirm to work will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest one (or a combination) of these options:

```
event.cancelBubble = true;
event.stopPropagation();
return false;
```